# Non-inverting op amp on breadboard isn't working

Tags: arduino, voltage, breadboard

I have posted this before and I have another question. I just can't get this working on a breadboard. I don't know what I am doing wrong. My voltage source is from an Arduino UNO which outputs a 5 volt max. Below the schematic is what I have done on a breadboard and I'm sure it's totally wrong. But the right of the picture the red and black cables are going to the V2 supply and and two black and red cables stick up are the outputs. Can anyone suggest what I can do differently or at least show me with their version on a breadboard?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUHQAc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Why is your capacitor flapping around? What is the capacitor for? What are you trying to do? Is this some kind of PWM scheme? Should it go to 0? If so why are you using a 741?

Answer (score 1):

A uA741 will only be able to get within about 1V of the minus supply typically, and within 5V minimum 2V typical of the + supply with a 2K load. The 741 is not a single-supply op-amp.

Increase R2 and R3 to more like 10K each and it should 'typically' give you 10V out with a 12V supply. It's not guaranteed though and is not good design. Better to use a more appropriate op-amp within its datasheet guaranteed limits.

A better choice would be 1/2 an LM358 which is an ultra-cheap single supply dual op-amp.

By the way, this is not a "voltage doubler" which by convention applies to a power supply. It is an amplifier with a gain of +2. The power is intended to come from the 12V supply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with R1 , in your breadboard as it seems it has both its ends in same node. 
Also just cross check whether you have used correct arduino pin labels , GND , and it seems you are using pin 9 as output for arduino so cross check your **code** again , make sure it is an **output pin** and you are sending a **HIGH** to that pin.

Also you should give a thought to above answers as to what good design practices are and what a voltage doubler is , a term used in power systems and your circuit is an non inverting amplifier with a gain of 2 , as already mentioned above

[image]

Comment: Good observation, but not actually relevant to the problem, which exists regardless of the value of R1.

Comment: yes it should not be causing any problems but you can't really debug more with a  keen eye , theoretically the schematic is correct , and this is the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

As Spehro said, "The 741 is not a single-supply op-amp." That means that the circuit must use a split supply, not a single supply.

`+V` and `-V` are relative to ground. You need two power sources. For `+V`, connect the `-` side of one source to ground and the `+` side to `+V`; for the `-V`, connect the `+` side of the other source to ground and the `-` side to `-V`. Get rid of the connection from `-V` to ground.